# multiple thermostat runs using one cable

Tags: wiring

I'm looking to hook up 4 seperate HVACS to an enviromental control system -
All four thermostats are near each other - but it's @ 150 foot run to control system.
Each HVAC only requires 3 conductors. Can i run 1 18/12 to pick up all 4 HVACS (thermostats)? just wondering
if there would be any heat issues or something -
Thanks

Comment: that is a wired set up, please give more information

Comment: If you're comfortable stripping the insulation off small sections of your 18/12 that are no where near the end of the cable, then effectively you can pull this off with no issues. 18AWG is plenty for HVAC controls.

Comment: 4 systems with thermostats 150 away? Is this *home* improvement or something else?

Comment: You appear to be talking about running one **cable**, not **wire**. I took the liberty of editing your title.

Comment: it really depends.  do all three HVACs connect to the same termInals on the ECS

Answer (score 1):

The 18AWG wires are suitable for HVAC control signal.

The control signal is 24 Volt and relatively low current so no danger from overloading or over heating the wires.

as you say you have 3 wires per thermostat, two would be for 24 Volt, and the third one is for signal.